# How can one copy photos off an iPad onto a Windows computer (prior to syncing)?

Tags: itunes, ipad, data-synchronization, windows, photos

My father wants to sync a bunch of photos from his Windows PC to his iPad for a presentation.  But he's never synced photos before.  And he's downloaded a number of photos from his camera directly to his iPad.  I fear his iPad contains the only copy of some of his photos, and he doesn't want to loose them.  When my father turns on photo syncing in iTunes, he gets a warning that photos on the iPad not previously synced will be lost.

If my father was using a Mac, I would tell him to open iPhoto and download the photos from the iPad before syncing.  How can he do the equivalent with Windows (or perhaps with an app)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://blog.laptopmag.com/how-to-quickly-transfer-images-from-an-ipad-to-a-pc

A PC, like a Mac, will see the iPad as a camera. Instead of using an application to load the photos, you can just browse to them in Windows Explorer and copy them to a local folder.

Comment: Alternatively, you can run the Windows Camera Wizard with the iPad attached and it should recognize it as a camera and ask if you want to import all the pictures off it. On XP it was found under `All Programs -> Accessories` -- not sure where it'd be on a newer Windows OS.

Comment: I don't see it on my Windows 7 Enterprise install.